# Inter-component JS/TS, loading dynamically in angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hello current component structure is

```
appComponent
--infoComponent
    ---beforeComponent
    ---afterComponent
```

Now both before & after components consist of navbar with corresponding id's say `navbar_before`, `navbar_after`

Question 1:
Can i write code using JS/TS in info to load either of before/after component, using `{{ }}` based on some js/ts condition? I shouldn't be giving

```
<app-before></app-before>
<app-after></app-after>
```

directly in infoComponent. It should be given as a variable

Question 2: If yes to Question 1, how to access the navbar element with ID of before/after component from infoComponent like `var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");`

Gist: I am trying a sticky navbar on scroll with different menu's
Hope someone can provide few sources on how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define before component and after component as a child component of the parent component ("info component") by adding the two components inside the parent component html.

You have to use *ngIf in the child component to show which component needs to be rendered. You can declare a typescript variable in parent component ts file and then access that variable value in child components using @Input().